# I got same SHA-1 and SHA-256 key in my all project. How can I solve it?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I got same SHA-1 and SHA-256 key in my all project. How can I solve it?
In my all project same code I got.

Comment: generate new keystore file for every project

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is `debug.keystore` for default Keystore use, so whenever you want to get SHA-1 or SHA-256 key android studio will use that default Keystore `(debug.keystore)` to get SHA-1 and SHA-256 keys and so they are generated same every time for debug mode.

Now to generate different keys you have to delete the `debug.keystore` from  "users/.android/"(may be different for you) then rebuild your project again and see a new SHA1 and SHA-256 key will be generated.